# Thread ID From thread name

Tags: winapi

How can I get the thread ID of a Win32 thread from the thread name?

Comment: There is no way to get a thread by name...

Answer (score 1):

Win32 threads [don't have names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block). Did you mean process?

Comment: Threads have names ;) at least inside the debugger... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If, by name, you mean HANDLE, you can use :

```
DWORD WINAPI GetThreadId(
  _In_  HANDLE Thread
);
```

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)